# Enable button on MainActivity based on spinner OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm very new to android development and this is basically my first app.

I followed the guide on developer.android.com and other souces on the internet to work with spinners.

On my main activity, I have a spinner and a button and what I would like to do is to Enable (setClickable) the button based on the spinner selected item.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {    

private Spinner spinner1;   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);              

    //Add items to spinner 1 dynamically
    addItemsOnSpinner1();    
    addListenertoSpinner();        
}          

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addItemsOnSpinner1(){
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Test 1");
    list.add("Test 2");
    list.add("Add new");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);       
}

public void addListenertoSpinner(){
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());    
}           

}
```

I have successfully created an OnItemSelectedListener class from which I can display the spinner selected item text:

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()== "Add new"){
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
                "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
    }

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

My question is:

How can I set the Button.setClickable? 
I tried doing something like:

```
if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()== "Add new"){
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setClickable(true);                                  
    }
```

but the application crashes...

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Crashes with what error? Posting the logCat might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I've been also trying the debug to try to find out the error but the Logcat gives so much information... Is there a way to get the error? If I place a breakpoint just before initializing the Button b1 and I press F5, then a Class File Editor error is shown "source not found... The JAR file ....android.jar has no source attachment"

Comment: Assuming you're using Eclipse, LogCat should create a session filter for your app name (which is usually your base package name ex. com.google). If not you can write your own filter. You can also change the kind of log messages that LogCat reports (right now it's probably set to verbose, so look for a dropdown box with that in it, and select a different option, probably error). Further more, thrown exceptions should show up in red text in the LogCat window

Comment: Thanks for that. I have selected error and this is what is shown:

Comment: 08-29 14:12:40.782: E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 14:12:40.782: E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: and there are at least another 15 errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't extend from activity just for a listener. Try this

```
public void addListenertoSpinner(){
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()== "Add new"){
                Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                b1.setClickable(true);                                  
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });    
}
```

This creates an anonymous class (within the concept of the CURRENT activity) that can safely use `findViewById()`.

Comment: so what would be the advantage in extending (as they show on developer.android.com)?

Comment: So you can only extend from Activities if they are going to be activities (e.g. they're going to be displayed on your application). Instead of creating a new application, you can *implement* the interface in your MainMenu Activity. Then instead of saying `spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ...)` you would do `spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`. However, if your activity implements the interface you can only have one implementation. So if you had TWO spinners you would be out of luck. I prefer the anonymous class method, it's more flexible (if a bit harder to read).